# QtQuick Item.children.indexOf() doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, arrays, qml, qtquick2

Apparently, `children` property, which is documented to be a `list<Item>`, doesn't have the Javascript built-in `indexOf(element)`. The following code:

```
Item{
    id: exampleParent
    Item{ id: exampleChild }
}

Button{
    text: "Get index"
    onClicked: console.log(exampleParent.children.indexOf(exampleChild))
}
```

will throw a `TypeError: Property 'indexOf' of object [object Object] is not a function` error.

Why is this the case, is there any specific reason? Is there a better solution than manually traversing the `children` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this the case, is there any specific reason?

The [documentation for QML's list type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-list.html) says:

> A list value can be accessed in a similar way to a JavaScript array:
>
> - Values are assigned using the [] square bracket syntax with
>     comma-separated values
> - The length property provides the number of
>     items in the list
> - Values in the list are accessed using the [index]
>     syntax

It doesn't provide all of the API that you'd find in a JavaScript array.

The C++ counterpart is documented [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmllistproperty.html).

> Is there a better solution than manually traversing the `children` array?

No.

Answer (score 5):

Mitch gave a good explanation as to why you can't directly call `indexOf`, but there is a way to do it indirectly. You can use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) on [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) :

```
Row {
    Item{
        id: exampleParent
        Item{}
        Item{ id: exampleChild }
    }

    Button{
        text: "Get index"
        onClicked: console.log(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(exampleParent.children, exampleChild))
    }
}
```